# How to delete gray bar in blank activity

Tags: android

When I add new blank activity to android project, in editor I see on the top of screen grey bar with icon and application name. How can I delet it?
(Android 3.2)

Comment: can you paste your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just paste this attribute in your manifest file in `<application>` or `<activity>` tag

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

By putting this in `<Application>` tag will -> Remove the title bar in every activity that you created.

or if you put it in `<Activity>` only. The activity itself will don't have a title bar

Comment: How about this ``android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar``

Answer (score 3):

Put Code in Android Manifest File.

```
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

In `<application>` or `<activity>` TAG.

Answer (score 1):

Go in your AndroidManifest.xml file and use this code:

```
<activity android:name=".className"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

That gray bar is called `ActionBar` you can remove this by setting the following attribute to your `Activity` in manifest `<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">`

You can refer to [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) documentation for more details

Comment: @android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar requires API level 11 (current min is 
 8)

Comment: For versions less than 3.0 `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` will work

Answer (score -1):

I was succeed with following codes(API 16):

```
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar"
```

what I did is just change

> Apptheme

to

> Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

I hope it can help others.:)